# How can I summarize table with multiple conditions

Tags: powerbi

I have a table like

Table

| name | count | Include | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | true | 1 |
| abc | 2 | true | 1 |
| abc | 3 | true | 2 |
| abc | 1 | true | 2 |
| abc | 1 | false | 2 |
| def | 1 | true | 1 |
| def | 1 | false | 1 |

I have a summary table which sum each name when `Include` is true.

```
SummaryTable = CALCULATETABLE (
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Table',
        'Table'[name], "count", sum('Table'[count])
), 'Table'[Include] = TRUE)
```

But I want to create the sum based on different type so that

```
    SummaryTable = CALCULATETABLE (
        SUMMARIZE (
            'Table',
            'Table'[name], "type 1 count", sum('Table'[count] , when type == 1),
"type 2 count", sum('Table'[count] , when type == 2),
    ), 'Table'[Include] = TRUE)
```

I don't see a way to put 'FILTER' as a parameter to sum or sumx.

Can you please tell me how can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your Summarize block with:

```
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE('Table','Table'[name])
    ,"type 1 count", CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[count]), type = 1)
    ,"type 2 count", CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[count]), type = 2)
)
```